# Webpack with Yarn won't run post-compile commands

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

I am using yarn and running `yarn prod`. Error looks like this:

[image: result]

I guess it's stuck at this part:

```
mix.then(() => {
execSync(`npm run rtlcss ${__dirname}/Assets/css/admin.css ${__dirname}/Assets/css/admin.rtl.css`);
execSync(`npm run rtlcss ${__dirname}/Assets/css/dashboard.css ${__dirname}/Assets/css/dashboard.rtl.css`);});
```

However running this command manually works and I also have dev folder where it executes successfully (running same `yarn prod`).

Master and dev branches are merged so they are identical.

So what’s the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with centos permissions, fixed it and now it does work fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what the problem was and how you fixed it? Your answer can possibly help future users who encounter the same problem.